# Pyinstaller Executable File Not Running

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I am trying to convert a .py script into an executable file. I have researched this question on other threads but have not been able to find a solution.

My steps:

1. my code runs as expected on my console with no errors. What it does it verifies with the user (using tkinter GUI) that the user uploaded specific files to a specific folder. Then takes information from those files and creates an output (excel) and drops it into the same folder.
2. I created a separate environment for this code. The only modules I am using are:
   tkinter, pandas, numpy, datetime, xlsxwriter and time
3. I opened my command prompt and directed it to my directory (see below, line 1)
4. I ran pyinstaller directing it to create one file because the end users will need to be able to use it as is, not with a whole directory (see below, line 2)

5. When the command prompt signifies its done, I check the dist folder and verify there is an exe. file in there. However, when I click on it to run, all it does is open a blank command prompt:
   [![enter image description here][3]][3]

Things I've tried: I read on a different thread that I can alter the .spec file so that console = False would stop the cmd prompt from opening. That didn't seem to have any effect (and nothing else happened either).

Any advice on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Also, I am not sure if it is helpful, but here is the full screen of the cmd prompt as it ran when I executed pyinstaller:

```
(base) C:\Users\439528> cd C:/Users/439528/Python Scripts/Spyder

(base) C:\Users\439528\Python Scripts\Spyder>pyinstaller --onefile Remote_Audit_App_1.0.py
1137 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.10
1137 INFO: Python: 3.9.7 (conda)
1152 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
1152 INFO: wrote C:\Users\439528\Python Scripts\Spyder\Remote_Audit_App_1.0.spec
1152 INFO: UPX is not available.
1152 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\439528\\Python Scripts\\Spyder']
1652 INFO: checking Analysis
1652 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
1652 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
1652 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
1670 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5562 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
5572 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib'
8595 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
8778 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
8789 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\439528\Anaconda3\python.exe
8992 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\439528\Python Scripts\Spyder\Remote_Audit_App_1.0.py
11568 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
11568 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
23823 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
30985 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
41048 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
72723 INFO: Processing module hooks...
72723 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-appdirs.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
72733 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-bcrypt.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
72733 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
72733 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cryptography.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
72945 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-docutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
74880 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-IPython.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
75429 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jedi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
76820 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
76838 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jsonschema.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
76854 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.etree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
76854 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
77217 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nacl.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
77239 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nbconvert.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
77355 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nbformat.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
77402 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-notebook.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
80355 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-openpyxl.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
80477 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-parso.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
80485 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-py.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
80796 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
80796 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytest.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
81713 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pythoncom.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
82280 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pywintypes.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
82841 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-regex.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
82842 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-tables.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
82844 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32com.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
83566 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zmq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
85044 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-babel.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
85256 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
85266 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
85270 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
85274 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
85346 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gevent.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
85772 INFO: Determining a mapping of distributions to packages...
160930 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement zope.interface from package gevent.
160930 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement zope.event from package gevent.
160930 INFO: Packages required by gevent:
['cffi', 'greenlet', 'setuptools']
161982 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
161998 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-importlib_metadata.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
161998 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
162036 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
162675 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    backend Gtk3Agg requires cairo
162993 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
163316 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name '_macosx' from 'matplotlib.backends' (C:\Users\439528\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py)
164040 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": added
<string>:12: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg backend was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
164450 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Agg": added
164762 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
165153 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": added
165466 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
165903 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added
166340 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkCairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
166782 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added
167211 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
167517 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
167819 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXCairo": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
168182 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
168487 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
168904 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
169329 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
169686 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
170036 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
170471 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
170877 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
171196 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
171212 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
171285 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'f2py'
171331 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy._pytesttester.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
171339 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
171340 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.io.formats.style.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
171472 INFO: Note: NumExpr detected 12 cores but "NUMEXPR_MAX_THREADS" not set, so enforcing safe limit of 8.
171472 INFO: NumExpr defaulting to 8 threads.
171616 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.plotting.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
171899 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
172375 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
172384 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
172725 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
172740 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
172756 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
172756 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
173626 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
173626 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
173634 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pygments.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
175038 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
175675 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
175734 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
175848 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtSvg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
176052 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
176256 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytz.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
176460 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.linalg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
176460 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
176468 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
176468 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.spatial.transform.rotation.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
176578 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
176578 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
176578 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.stats._stats.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
176578 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
177743 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sphinx.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
183057 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlalchemy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
183441 WARNING: Hidden import "MySQLdb" not found!
183441 WARNING: Hidden import "psycopg2" not found!
185950 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
186019 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
186019 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-wcwidth.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
186035 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32ctypes.core.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
186267 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
186267 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
186267 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
186267 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zope.interface.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
186267 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
186405 INFO: checking Tree
186405 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
186405 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
186483 INFO: checking Tree
186483 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
186483 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
186552 INFO: checking Tree
186552 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
186552 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
186552 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.isoschematron.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
186567 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.objectify.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
186567 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
186723 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
186918 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
186938 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_subprocess.py'
186938 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
186946 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
186948 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_win32api.py'
186948 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
186948 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
186948 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
186956 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
186956 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_traitlets.py'
186956 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
186956 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
187009 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
187810 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp39-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\439528\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\socket.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
187826 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp39-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\439528\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\utils.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
187826 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp39-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\439528\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\context.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
187826 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp39-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\439528\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\_poll.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
187841 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp39-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\439528\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\message.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
187841 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp39-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\439528\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\_version.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
187841 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp39-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\439528\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\_proxy_steerable.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
187857 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp39-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\439528\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\_device.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
187857 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp39-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\439528\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\error.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
188891 INFO: Looking for eggs
188893 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\439528\Anaconda3\python39.dll
188893 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
188908 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\439528\Python Scripts\Spyder\build\Remote_Audit_App_1.0\warn-Remote_Audit_App_1.0.txt
189337 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\439528\Python Scripts\Spyder\build\Remote_Audit_App_1.0\xref-Remote_Audit_App_1.0.html
189558 INFO: checking PYZ
189558 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
189560 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\439528\Python Scripts\Spyder\build\Remote_Audit_App_1.0\PYZ-00.pyz
194005 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\439528\Python Scripts\Spyder\build\Remote_Audit_App_1.0\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
194087 INFO: checking PKG
194087 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
194095 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) Remote_Audit_App_1.0.pkg
282009 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) Remote_Audit_App_1.0.pkg completed successfully.
282160 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\439528\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
282160 INFO: checking EXE
282160 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
282160 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
282160 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\Users\439528\Python Scripts\Spyder\dist\Remote_Audit_App_1.0.exe.notanexecutable
282176 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
282176 INFO: Copying icons from ['C:\\Users\\439528\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\bootloader\\images\\icon-console.ico']
282176 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes
282176 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes
282176 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes
282176 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 1384 bytes
282176 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 37019 bytes
282176 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes
282176 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes
282176 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes
282176 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
282176 INFO: Emedding manifest in EXE
282176 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\439528\Python Scripts\Spyder\dist\Remote_Audit_App_1.0.exe.notanexecutable
282176 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
282191 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
355155 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

I keep seeing spots where it says 'not an executable' and I'm thinking those lines are part of the problem, but am a little lost on how to resolve. TIA

**EDIT:** I have found that if I click in the command prompt, or hit enter and wait a few seconds, my GUI window pops up. But then when I interact with it, it freezes up and displays (not responding)
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkK32.png

Answer (score 0):

After some further investigation, the issue was with the file pathways being mapped differently for different users. The script I wrote was not able to access the correct files in order to run.